# how to stop current transaction in Jmeter on sampler error?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my Test Plan , i have multiple transactions(not related). Is there a way to stop just the current transaction only on a sampler error. If I use the setting to stop thread/ continue next thread , it just drops the thread for each transactions, which is not very helpful for what i want to achieve. Any help please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "transaction"?

"Sample error" can be caught by [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) using `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) as the condition and from there you can:

1. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and use one of below 3 actions:

   [image]
2. Or add a [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) pointing to a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) holding the actions which you would like to execute on Sampler's error. See [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: by transactions i mean I have multiple transactional controller in my thread group